# Create react app using npx create-react-app failed

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a React app using npx by using command

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

then I got a bunch of errors which is saying

```
error Couldn't find package "@svgr/webpack@4.3.3" required by "react-scripts" on the "npm" registry.
Error: Couldn't find package "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^2.10.0" required by "react-scripts" on the "npm" registry.
Error: Couldn't find package "@typescript-eslint/parser@^2.10.0" required by "react-scripts" on the "npm" registry.
Error: Couldn't find package "@xtuc/ieee754@^1.2.0" required by "@webassemblyjs/ieee754@1.8.5" on the "npm" registry.
Error: Couldn't find package "@xtuc/long@4.2.2" required by "@webassemblyjs/leb128@1.8.5" on the "npm" registry.
Error: Couldn't find package "@xtuc/long@4.2.2" required by "@webassemblyjs/wast-printer@1.8.5" on the "npm" registry.
Error: Couldn't find package "@xtuc/long@4.2.2" required by "@webassemblyjs/wast-parser@1.8.5" on the "npm" registry.
```

Then, the installation aborted, I have already tried to clean npm cache using'

```
npm cache clean --force
```

but it still getting the same error, is there any solution for this problem? thank you!

Comment: There is some issue with npm

Comment: is there any other way instead of using npm? I also use `yarn create react-app my-app` but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM is currently having problems, you can see the latest updates here: https://status.npmjs.org/

Comment: is there any other way instead of using npm? I have tried using `yarn create react-app my-app` but still the same